# How to pass text style information to database?

Tags: forms, text, styles

I have a form, where users can write and submit article to a database. 
These articles are then published on the site using mysgli (finally got prepared statements to work :P)

What I now ideally would like to have; is the user to be able to do some styling. Just like as I'm writing this I have the option to style some text as 'code'.

However I'm completely lost on how to do this. Could anyone please point me in the right direction?

Cheers,
Ziggy

Comment: What programming language are you using? Is this a web based application, or a desktop one?

Comment: No notice about the language you use or the way you're saving data right now.

Comment: Well, SO uses Markdown - you could look into using that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a simple problem.

You should make your mind up regarding:

- what kind of format to support
- how to render the format of your webpage

E.g. you could use Wiki formatting.  In your database entries you would have the formatting as part of the text (e.g. the 4 spaces indentation for code blocks). You further will need a renderer that is able to present this text with the formatting info on your site.

Possible formats to consider are Wikitext, HTML+CSS, Richtext.

However, you could ask yourself if maybe using an existing Wiki will be easier insted. Not sure what your project is.